# healpy install on osx: unable to find cfitsio

Tags: python, macos, healpy

I'm trying to install healpy on my Mac OSX 10.8.5 machine. I downloaded the latest copy from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/healpy/1.6.3, unpacked it and tried the command:

```
python setup.py build
```

as it says in the docs, but I keep getting the following error:

```
checking if library 'cfitsio' is installed

error: No such file or directory
```

1) I do have it and 2) if I didn't it says it should be okay because it's all included in the folder.

So, I tried to do it again using pip:

```
pip install healpy
```

and got the same error.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly more suitable for http://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: I think the "No such file or directory" is a bit of a red herring and doesn't apply to 'cfitsio'. Did you try `sudo pip install healpy` or `pip install healpy --user` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried both of those and got the same message both times.

Comment: can you paste all your output to a [gist](http://gist.github.com)?

Comment: what about installing from macports? http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=healpy

Comment: You tried with `sudo` in front? May be something wrong with your setuptools or pip installation. If you look in the healpy `setup.py` file, the message for a missing library is not "No such file or directory" so it is probably the installation environment that is missing something. Can you do `sudo easy_install pip` successfully? (In my experience macports is more susceptible to conflicts and will try to install its own python from scratch.)

Comment: * The pip reinstall should probably be `sudo easy_install -U pip`

Comment: Final thought. Do you have dev tools installed? I.e. `which gcc` and `which clang` find things?

Comment: I've pasted my pip.log into [link](https://gist.github.com/jbkalmbach/6818159).

Comment: And yes, dev tools is installed and my pip seems to be fine.